# Char array of array values to pointer array

Tags: c, microcontroller, xc8

I need put array of array chat values in to pointer array. for that first I used code like this and it works for me.

```
char *current_tag_lists[20];
char current_tag_list1[]="0005808897";
char current_tag_list2[]="0009953997";
char current_tag_list3[]="0000116600"; 
current_tag_lists[0] = current_tag_list1;
current_tag_lists[1] = current_tag_list2;
current_tag_lists[2] = current_tag_list3;
```

so I can access the value by index `current_tag_lists[0]`.

But my actual requirement is to add these value in run time as follows. This is a example code.

```
char *current_tag_lists[20];

while(k<6)
 {
    char RFID_input_characters[12];
    while(a<13){
        if(a==12){
            current_tag_lists[k]=RFID_input_characters;
            a=0;
            k++;
            break;
        }
        else{
            RFID_input_characters[a]='a'; // this example in my code it get value like this
            a++;
       }
     }
   }
```

But the problem is that "current_tag_lists" does not store all the values. it only store the current value. It every time replace the previous value. i need to keep the values as my above example and need to access from index (current_tag_lists[0]).

Can anyone please help me. 
This is my actual code.

```
while(k<6)//while(!(c1==1))
{
    char RFID_input_characters[12]={0};
    while(a<14){


        if (a == 0) {
            ReceiveByteSerially();
            a++;
        }

        else if (a == 13 ) {
            ReceiveByteSerially();
            current_tag_lists[k] = malloc(strlen(RFID_input_characters) + 1);
            strcpy(current_tag_lists[k], RFID_input_characters);
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
            Lcd_Write_String(RFID_input_characters);
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
             Lcd_Write_String(current_tag_lists[k]);
            a = 0;
            k++;
            break;
        }
        else if(k%2!=0 && a==1){
             char x=ReceiveByteSerially();
             if((x!=0x02)&&(x!=0X03)){
                a++;
             }
        }
        else{
            char x=ReceiveByteSerially();
             if((x!=0x02)&&(x!=0X03)){
                 if(k%2 !=0){
                     RFID_input_characters[a-2] = x;
                 }
                 else if(a<12){
                RFID_input_characters[a-1] = x;
                 }
                a++;
        }
        }
    }

}
```

please only look the if(a==13).

This is my error log.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.33\sources\common\strcpy.c:19:     error: (1466) registers  unavailable for code generation of this expression
 (908) exit status = 1
 make[2]: ***      [dist/default/production/Super_Smart_Backpack.X.production.hex] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2`
`nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:119: recipe for target  'dist/default/production/Super_Smart_Backpack.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/Irushi-final/Super Smart Backpack.X/Super   Smart Backpack.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:78: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/Irushi-final/Super Smart Backpack.X/Super Smart Backpack.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: There are several problems here.  This link might help: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr

Comment: Can you please just pointed out me the problems. I'm stuck because of this.

Comment: Look at user30020's example below: 1) allocate an array to hold 20 tag lists: `char *current_tag_lists[20];`, 2) 2) Allocate a string buffer to hold a single tag: `current_tag_lists[k] = malloc(strlen(RFID_input_characters) + 1);`, 3) Copy the tag data into the newly allocated element in your array: `strcpy(current_tag_lists[k], RFID_input_characters);`.  In other words, you need to allocate your "list", *AND* you also need to allocate space for each item in the list.  You need to use a function like "strcpy()" to copy the data..

Comment: Sidenote:; for your indentation style, it is better to have `else` on the same line as the preceeding if's  `}`.

Comment: @Kristian: please specify the C compiler you're using. If this is a microcontroller, it's possible your compiler/standard library doesn't have "malloc()" or "free()".

Comment: @paulsm4: I was just about to write the same.:-)

Comment: At a glance your code seems to be ok. Maybe the compiler is the culprit. Actually its `strcpy`.

Comment: Aside some bug on the compiler itself (or its `strcpy`) you could merge together the `malloc` and `strcpy` with `strdup`.

Comment: can you please give me sample code

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

If I got you correctly.

```
// First you create a normal null terminated string and copy some test string to it
char RFID_input_characters[12]="test";
....
// Now since you have array of pointers, you can allocate some space 
// and set k-th pointer point to it
current_tag_lists[k] = malloc(strlen(RFID_input_characters) + 1);

// Now you can copy something to the memory you allocated
strcpy(current_tag_lists[k], RFID_input_characters);
```

don't forget to `free` later.

The way you had it always you were setting each pointer point to the same address - that is starting address of array `RFID_input_characters` (the assignment you had there was not copying the string, just setting k-th pointer point to the start of `RFID_input_characters` array. To copy strings you can use `strcpy` or its safer versions for instance).

Comment: You should add some explanatory text what was wrong and what you did. That will help future readers. Is there a reason for the initializer? If that is an `auto` variable, it costs unnecessary runtime, otherwise unnecessary memory, if the compiler is not smart.

Comment: @Olaf: I always initialize variables in C; the cost you mention is not very big I guess

Comment: Well, using an uninitialized variable is discouraged anyway. However, you actually do twice: using an initializer and the function call. For a global variable, that is nonsense, as it is always set `0` according to the standard. And for a local that might be runtime critical. Just note: this is for a microcontroller, not a PC! One has to adopt his programming style to the platform. (No wonder why theres so much embedded systems with crap code.)

Comment: I updated my issue with error code. Firstly I used global variable but same happen.

Comment: @Olaf: This was local variable I assumed, and really I have the habit to always initialize them. Also the way I have it even if you forget to null terminate it later, it is already null terminated (just accepts 11 characters)

Comment: you need to include headers for strcpy etc. e.g. #include <string.h>

Comment: It is definitively bad style for an MCU. Mostly as you overwrite with the following statement. I just do not undestand, why you not just write `char RFID_input_characters[12] = "test";`? Note that the strcpy() will exhibit UB  already. if there is not enough space in the array. Please rethink your code. and your arguments.

Comment: char RFID_input_characters[12] = "test"; - can be fine. My arguments are rethought :) Habbit to always initialize variables. and in general when I do like this ={0} even if later I forget to null terminate the string it is already null terminated

Comment: I see only one error source code related and that mentions strcpy, that is why I suggested include

Comment: i added above example still same problem.  I got those errors.  (1466) registers  unavailable for code generation of this expression

 (1467) read-only target "STR_75" may be indirectly written via pointer

Comment: @Kristian: First just write one line to make sure strcpy works on other project

Comment: @user30020: Why do you think I downvoted? I did actually not (just for the flaws?). Currently you do not have any downvotes! Note: If that was you who downvotetd an answer of mine in to another question, actually, that might be a reason for moderator attention! (starting kindergarten games?)

Comment: It seems strcpy and malloc gives error. :( what should i do for this

Comment: @Kristian: Like I said first take empty project and check how to use strcpy and malloc - or find out how to do that with that microcontroller. Otherwise you can also search two dimensional char arrays to do it without malloc ..

Comment: @Kristian: does your environment even have the standard library? A C compiler is not required to support that actually and small embedded systems actually tend not to. That is called a _freestanding implementation_ (for the compiler), resp. _freestanding environment_ for the (well - environment). According to another comment: if you are working on 8 bit PIC actually, forget about `malloc()` and stuff. also note that **unnecessary(!)** initialization will eat up your code-space.

Comment: I have to ask for pardon! I just checked again. It was not you to downvote (neither did I!). I apparently missinterpreted the emoticons in your answers (you might be more careful with those) as sarcasm.

Comment: @Olaf:it's ok. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

given the posted code:

```
char *current_tag_lists[20];

while(k<6)
 {
    char RFID_input_characters[12];
    while(a<13){
        if(a==12){
            current_tag_lists[k]=RFID_input_characters;
            a=0;
            k++;
            break;
        }
        else{
            RFID_input_characters[a]='a'; // this example in my code it get value like this
            a++;
       }
     }
   }
```

There are several details that need attention:

1) need to initialize the current_tag_lists[] to all NULLs to make it easy when later the malloc'd strings need to be passed to free()

```
char *current_tag_lists[2] = { NULL };
```

2) each string needs a unique place to be stored:

```
char *temp =NULL;
if( NULL == (temp = malloc( 12 ) ) )
{ // then malloc failed
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    cleanup();  // frees all malloc'd areas
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

regarding this line:

```
while( a < 13 )
```

the max number of characters per entry is (per the original code and the above mallocf() 12.   C references offsets into arrays as 0...(array len -1)
So 12 (a<13) would be accessing beyond the upper bound of the array.
Leading to undefined behaviour, which can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Suggest the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // malloc, free

#define MAX_TAG_LISTS (20)
#define MAX_RFID_LEN (12)

char *current_tag_lists[ MAX_TAG_LISTS ];

// initialize current_tag_lists[] to make cleanup simple
memset( current_tag_lists, '\0', sizeof(current_tag_lists));

char *temp =NULL;
for( int k = 0; k < MAX_TAG_LISTS; k++ )
{
    if( NULL == (temp = malloc( MAX_RFID_LEN ) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        cleanup( current_tag_lists );  // frees all malloc'd areas
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for( int a = 0; a < MAX_RFID_LEN; a++ )
    {
         temp[a]='a'; // this example in my code it get value like this
    } // end for

    current_tag_lists[k]=temp;
    temp = NULL;
} // end for



void cleanup( char *current_tag_lists )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < MAX_TAG_LISTS; i++)
    {
        // note: ok to pass NULL to free
        free( current_tag_lists[i] );
    }
} // end function: cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

On a microcontroller you may not want to use `malloc` and your algorithm seems to have very determined needs, as it's normal for microcontrollers. In your algorithm

```
char *current_tag_lists[20];
while(k<6)
{
    char RFID_input_characters[12];
```

you define some numbers. First you should use symbols for the constants 20,6 and 12:

```
enum tag_list_params { tag_list_len=20, rfid_len=12, num_input_cycles=6 };
```

and replace them in your code.

Now you define the space

```
typedef char rfid_t[rfid_len];
rfid_t tag_list_space[tag_list_len];
```

then you can point with `current_tag_list` into the `tag_list_space`

```
char* current_tag_lists[20];
```

of course you could use the `&tag_list_space[a]` directly, but you can do

```
current_tag_lists[k]=(char*)&tag_list_space[k];
```

to use the variables as you defined them. When you write into the tag list, you can simply point into the space too

```
char* RFID_input_characters;
for(k=0;k<num_input_cycles;k++)
{
    current_tag_lists[k]=(char*)&tag_list_space[k]; /* save to your target structure */
    RFID_input_characters = (char*)&tag_list_space[k];
    for(a=0; a<rfid_len;++a) {
        RFID_input_characters[a] = 'a';
    }
}
```

The full test program might look similar to this:

```
/* enum tag_list_params { tag_list_len=20, rfid_len=12, num_input_cycles=6 }; */
#define tag_list_len 20
#define rfid_len 12
#define num_input_cycles 6

typedef char rfid_t[rfid_len];

char* current_tag_lists[tag_list_len]; /* this is the parameter you want to modify outside 
    you can define it as
        extern char** current_tag_list;
    if you export it in a header file */
static rfid_t tag_list_space[tag_list_len]; /* if you define the space inside of the function,
    the memory will get lost on function exit */

void all_a(void)
{
    int k, a;
    char* RFID_input_characters;
    for(k=0;k<num_input_cycles;k++)
    {
        current_tag_lists[k]=(char*)&tag_list_space[k]; /* save to your target structure */
        RFID_input_characters = (char*)&tag_list_space[k];
        for(a=0; a<rfid_len;++a) {
            RFID_input_characters[a] = 'a';
         }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    all_a();
}
```

From gdb output when all_a is ready:

```
(gdb) p current_tag_lists
$1 = {0x601080 <tag_list_space> 'a' <repeats 72 times>,
    0x60108c <tag_list_space+12> 'a' <repeats 60 times>,
    0x601098 <tag_list_space+24> 'a' <repeats 48 times>,
    0x6010a4 <tag_list_space+36> 'a' <repeats 36 times>,
    0x6010b0 <tag_list_space+48> 'a' <repeats 24 times>,
    0x6010bc <tag_list_space+60> 'a' <repeats 12 times>,
    0x0 <repeats 14 times>}
```

Comment: I don't use any functions from the library and this is valid code. What does not work? BTW: You shouldn't use `a` as an array index and as a control status flag as you did in your code.

Comment: @Kristian you might have a problem with enum or with the function definitions. I changed them in my example program. Finally your compiler might dislike `&tag_list_space[k]`, you can replace that by `tag_list_space + k` or you need to work with byte offsets directly: `char byte_space[tag_list_len*rfid_len];` and `current_tag_lists[k]=byte_space + (k*rfid_len)`. If that still does not compile you might not have a C compiler at all ;)

Comment: This still does not work . I don't know what to do ?

Comment: does not work is a strange error message. What does not work, what are the error messages from the compiler, where does it not work? Can you compile a hello_world.c with your compiler at all? I mean, my code does not depend on any library at all. Its just pure C code. When this does not work, your compiler uses a strange syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Actually char *current_tag_lists[20]; is an array of pointer to chars.
In this line current_tag_lists[k]=RFID_input_characters; you are storing the pointer RFID_input_characters in current_tag_lists[k] and not its contents. Since current_tag_lists[k] is pointing to memory address of RFID_input_characters , changing the contents of RFID_input_characters gets reflected in current_tag_lists[k].

You can change your code like this:

```
  char *current_tag_lists[20];
    while(k<6)
    {
        char RFID_input_characters[12];
        a=0;
        while(a<13){
            if(a==12){
                current_tag_lists[k]=malloc(12);
                strcpy(current_tag_lists[k],RFID_input_characters);
                break;
            }
            else{
                RFID_input_characters[a]='a'; // this example in my code it get value like this
                a++;
           }
         }
        k++;
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory allocated using malloc or you could end up using all your memory resources.

Comment: this line: 'strcpy(current_tag_lists[k],RFID_input_characters);'  will not work.  The reason is that current_tag_lists[] are ONLY pointers and they have not been set to point anywhere, for instance to malloc'd memory areas.

Comment: I think you are missing the line "current_tag_lists[k]=malloc(12)".